# Copy new files when they are created or updated

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

not sure if this is possible. I am trying to work out a way to copy new/updated files from a folder in a user's C drive to a server, but only want the script to run if a new file is created/updated in the source.

I would like to set this up for multiple users, trying to avoid scheduling a robocopy task to run daily. Below is the batch file id like to use, if only i can get it to know if a new file 'score.txt' has been created/updated.

```
for /f "delims=|" %%s in ('dir /ad/b') do robocopy "\\UserPC\C$\%%s\score.txt" "\\Server\e$\Users\%%s\Scores\" /E /MOVE /log:"\\Server\e$\Users\Scores.log"
```

If a scheduled task is the only option then please let me know.

Comment: Robocopy has switches to monitor a folder.  JFTR a scheduled task is not able to monitor a folder.

Comment: Like fox said robocopy has a monitoring component add `/MON:N` to the command (Were N is the number of changes to files and folders before the robocopy command runs again)

Comment: thanks, i didnt know about the /MON switch